# PowerShell RSA Decryption

Tags: powershell, encryption, rsa

Is there a way to decrypt RSA in PowerShell with the private key passed to the program as a string parameter instead of using a Certificate stored on the machine? Any help welcome, my code is below.

```
Function Decrypt-Asymmetric
{
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([System.String])]
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][System.String]
    $EncryptedBase64String,
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][System.String]
    $Cert
)

if($Cert) {
    $EncryptedByteArray = [Convert]::FromBase64String($EncryptedBase64String)
    $ClearText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($Cert.PrivateKey.Decrypt($EncryptedByteArray,$true))
}
Else {Write-Error "Certificate with thumbprint: $CertThumbprint not found!"}

Return $ClearText
}

$dec = Decrypt-Asymmetric "OZqKrQy56eclr/9pJRnguFzwKM3B8CqM+mxCqn5oGiTfh8/kp7r7Q+d+pxOBKmerkoscIsPHWdqGtds3CrmLog==" "PrivateKey as String"
$dec
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used SushiHangover's RSACrypto module in the past to decrypt email messages. You could also try to figure out what he did and implement it in your code.

https://github.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover-PowerShell/tree/master/modules/SushiHangover-RSACrypto

```
Import-Module SushiHangover-RSACrypto
$PemFile = $HOME + '\.ssh\SSH2RSA2048_private_test_key.pem'
$cypherBase64 = "OZqKrQy56eclr/9pJRnguFzwKM3B8CqM+mxCqn5oGiTfh8/kp7r7Q+d+pxOBKmerkoscIsPHWdqGtds3CrmLog=="
$decBytes = Get-RSAClearBytes $cypherBase64 $false
$decText = Get-RSAClearText $cypherBase64 $false
```

Cheers
Glenn